# Onsen UI Carousel and sliding menu

Tags: carousel, onsen-ui, slidingmenu

In my application, in a page I have a carousel in toolbar, to have a top fixed position.

The Carousel is not visible until I put a position:fixed in a div containing the carousel.

In this page I have a sliding menu too.

When I slide the sliding menu, the carousel remains fixed in the view, over the sliding menu, instead to swipe right in the page.

I experienced this problem in Android default browser and like a builed app in Android. In the desktop browser (Firefox and Crome) it's all ok.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my carousel issues with the sliding menu just by containing in in an  column. If you have to, you may have to adjust the width to be under the set for the sliding menu. It may even work with width being set at 100% but, putting it in its own column or row helped me out a lot avoiding those overlapping issues.

Example:

```
<ons-row><ons-col width="10%"></ons-col>
       <ons-col width="80%"><br /><h4>Carousel</h4>
        <ons-list-item>
        <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll style="height: 50px; width: 100%; align: center;" initial-index="0" swipe-target-width="100">
        <ons-carousel-item class="button--menu">
        Item 0
        </ons-carousel-item>
         <ons-carousel-item class="button--menu">
        Item 1
        </ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel>
        </ons-list-item>
```